# Weird Javascript Issue

Tags: cartthrob, jquery

Not strictly EE but I'm flummoxed all the same.

I'm trying to clean up zyteq.com.au and on this URL (http://zyteq.propeller-dev2.com/products/software) I've taken out jquery Match Height and resolved the product container sizing with CSS.

However this javascript remains and is causing all three product links in the row to direct to the URL of the first:-

```
    $("#products_box").children().hover(

    function(){

        $(this).addClass("hover");

    }, 

    function(){

        $(this).removeClass("hover");

    }

).click(function(e){

    url = $(this).find("a").first().attr("href");

    if (typeof(url) != 'undefined') {

        window.location = url;

        e.preventDefault();

    }

});
```

Any ideas what that does and why anyone would use it? Is it connected to jquery match height or CartThrob in any way?

Just to be sure, the last developers included it in no less than three js files…
If I comment it out the link issue is solved but without understanding what it does I'm reluctant to remove it altogether.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's pretty munted. Presumably trying to make it IE6 compatible prevented them from just using :hover on divs and using an anchor as each .item HTML5 style.

The javascipt is attempting to do some pretty run of mill stuff:

a) it's adding a .hover class to the #products_box children on hover, which are the .row-span divs, not the .item elements. (easily replaced with just css)

b) if you click on one, and it's an .item, find the first link within the .item and point the user to the url in the anchor. (it's broken as it's just finding the first anchor in each .row-span, not the anchor in the .item the user is clicking on)

If it was me, I'd remove the js and just use CSS for the hover styles, and rewrite the html to make the .item an anchor, wrapping all the internal items.

Done!

Comment: Thanks mate. I added the row-span div when I stripped out the Match Height js and changed the CSS to display:table etc. I figured as much as what you said there - just wasnt sure so wasnt keen to strip it out. The whole site was pretty munted tbh but its almost there now.